# Can Facebook's Custom privacy setting ever include the public?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-privacy

On Facebook, I occasionally see certain friends with their privacy settings set to *Custom*. When I comment on their posts, I don't want my comments to show up publicly, but I can't know whether they will for sure because the *Custom* privacy setting is all that's shown.

From experimenting myself, it doesn't seem possible to set the Custom privacy setting to include the public, although I suppose there is always a possibility with Facebook's increasing tendency to test new features differently across regions.

Can the Custom privacy setting ever include the public, or will Friends of Friends always be as public as it gets?

Answer (score 1):

There was an experiment back in 2017 (https://thenextweb.com/facebook/2017/12/11/facebook-testing-private-comments-save-idiots/) I'm not sure if the feature is still available at the moment.

For the current privacy setup, no, as far I know, I don't think Public and Custom can be in the same privacy selection. I can see how "Custom" does not add confidence to the true privacy level however.